# Word Usage of “Match”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idioms

> Identify the sentence in which the usage of the word *match* is incorrect.
>
> 1. "This marriage is a match made in heaven" she gushed.
> 2. "Please light the match so that I can see the switch" said my friend.
> 3. It was an even match between the two contestants.
> 4. This movie sequel is not a match on the original.

I felt in sentence #4 the usage is incorrect. But some of my friends say it should be sentence #2. Could someone please clarify?

- "match made in heaven is an expression" used for describing a perfect compatibility.
- Expressions such as "evenly match" means somebody/something to be as good, interesting, successful
- I also found usage of *lighting a matchstick*.

Comment: Why do you think it's #4? Why do they think it is #2? What research have you and your friends done to come to these conclusions? What definitions of match have you found to make you not consider #1 and #3?

Comment: @Hank for #3 I could find usage as "evenly match" meaning  somebody/something to be as good, interesting, successful  for #1 could find that its an expression used for describing a perfect compatibility, and for #2 also I could find usage of lighting a matchstick

Comment: Please add all of that reasoning to the post.

Comment: Schoolwork questions are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker. The only exception is when there is a clearly identified source of concern about an element of the English language that would be interesting and useful to many future visitors.

Comment: @MetaEd How would the OP have known where to look? He did the research, inasmuch as he looked up the term *match* , and he added his thoughts and the plausible answer/s which were wrong. Only someone who has experience learning, teaching or speaking English would have known "why" No.4 was wrong.

Comment: So I suppose I now know why my answer, which not only is correct but also supported with reliable references, and appropriately cited, was downvoted.

Comment: @MetaEd I actually thought the question was interesting because it illustrated the different meanings of *match* and highlighted an idiom which many learners may be unaware of. In fact, I had one discussion with one user who insisted that "*not a match* ***for***" was correct, we have both deleted our comments, but being a mod I know you can read deleted comments. Was this answer not useful then to that  particular user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4. This movie sequel is not a <del>match</del> on the original.

No. 4 is inappropriate, the correct idiom is

### [not a patch on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_a_patch_on)

> Not nearly as good as: much worse than.
>   *Wiktionary*

*[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-be-a-patch-on-sth)* tells me it is a British English idiom.

- *The new model is **not a patch on** the original version*
- *This new washing machine **isn't a patch on** our old one.*

### [match](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/match)

(sentence #1)

> If two people who are having a relationship are a good match, they are very suitable for each other:
>
> - *Theirs is a match made in heaven* (= a very good relationship).

(sentence #2)

> a short, thin stick made of wood or cardboard and covered with a special chemical at one end that burns when rubbed firmly against a rough surface:
>
> - *a box of matches*
> - *You should always strike a match away from you.*

(sentence #3)

> a person or thing that is equal to another person or thing in strength, speed, or quality